# angularJS - ng-options source triggers ng-change on item disabling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a problem when using ng-options alongside ng-change ( I cannot use ng-repeat - the form is printed by a engine that automaticaly print the  and  )
I have two binded input ( let's say Number and Selections ), both triggering a function on change. 
ng-options set the data with an array of object with an Id and a Max and Min attribute.

```
<input ng-model="Number" ng-change="foo()"/>
<select ng-model="Selection" ng-options="disable when (item.max<Number || item.min > Number ) for item in datas" ng-change="foo()"/>
```

the selectable datas in the select is disabled depending on the Number model, some being selectable only if Number is in their range ( an attribute in item ; item.maxRange; item.minRange )

```
$scope.foo=function(){
    console.log("Foo Fighter on the roll !");
}
```

when changing the data of both input on the web page, foo() get called once for each, as normal
But if I start by selection an Item ( with ,let's say a Max value of 35  ), then enter a Number outside of the selected option ( let's say 50 ) 
the foo() function get called twice ( once for the Number change and once because the Item get unselected as it get disabled ).
Is there a way to prevent that second  foo() call when the item get disabled ?

I already tried `ng-model-options:{updateOn: "blur"}` and it stops both foo() on manual change and disabling for the select .
I intend to do some page modification for each foo() call, and it looks bugged if the function get called twice after inputing text once only.

**I have found an (evil) solution**
By evil I mean it is not THE perfect solution but some kind of ditry workaround 
I've decided to put a timer inside foo(), as the ng-change are fired simultaneously. That timer will prevent the call, and reset on each call. THus when both ng-change will launch , foo() shall be called only once !
**Still, the issue is still there, it is just a weird workaround**

Comment: Post sample Code @R.Damasinoro otherwise use ng-repeat as well ng-options

Comment: I see the issue. There isn't an easy way to do what you're saying. Do you need foo to be in an ng-change on both inputs? It would help if we knew what foo was doing.

Comment: foo() should trigger an Ajax call which send the input data to an API (the Number and Selected Item)
When foo() is called twice it send both the Number and Selected Item first, then once Angular disable the select and call foo() again, it send another call with Number only. And once the call is done, some graphic change are launched on the page ( twice !  which make the problem extremely visible and annoying to users )